# Coldfusion 10 AJAX replace content in cfdiv

Tags: ajax, jsp, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

I have an href that throws an error when trying to replace the contents of its parent cfdiv.

In the efforts to keep this short, the link looks something like this:

```
<cfdiv id="managerDiv">
    <a href="javascript:ColdFusion.navigate('theURL?theVariables','managerDiv');" >add a new thing</a>
</cfdiv>
```

The error that I'm getting is a dialog box that indicates the following:

**Error retrieving markup for element managerDiv : /manager/CFIDE/administrator/templates/errors.jsp [Enable debugging by adding 'cfdebug' to your URL parameters to see more information]**

---

A few things to note:

- On my Coldfusion 10 development environment, I have no problems.  This error only occurs on my hosting server.
- The directory structure of both my hosting and development environments is EXACTLY the same
- I do NOT have a pointer or mapping to "errors.jsp" anywhere in my source code or Coldfusion settings.
- manager is a sub-directory at the root level
- "theURL" is any coldfusion file, I have tried with a simple blank.cfm file, and it still passes the same error

---

Thoughts

Obviously, it seems like Coldfusion is looking for a file that doesn't exist to replace the contents of the cfdiv.  However, I really have no idea why it is looking for something other than the contents of "theURL", and why it is looking for it in the directory specified in the error (manager/CFIDE/...)

---

I did some more testing. 
It appears that the coldfusion.navigate URL parameter does not like the relative path *(again, it works fine on my dev environment, but not on production)*.

For example, this works:
`<a href='javascript.Coldfusion.navigate('test.cfm');'>`

but this does NOT:
`<a href='javascript.Coldfusion.navigate('folder/test.cfm');'>`

thoughts?

Comment: I would assume the CFIDE folder is locked down and you're not able to access it through your provider.

Comment: 1. Stop using <cfdiv> - or any of the UI components in ColdFusion for that matter. 2. Do you have access to log files? If so, check them out, it is possible in the CF Admin that a site wide error handler was set to error.jsp. Looking at the log files may shed some light on what the error is. 3. Try hitting the URL in the navigate() call directly in your browser and see what the result is.

Comment: I just looked at errors.jsp on my local install of CF 10 and it looks like the default 'error' page you get when you install Cf 10 with the 'secure' profile. Seems like you have an error somewhere in your code and it is causing CF to try and load that file.

Comment: Scott: Are you suggesting I don't use <cfdiv> for a final solution?  Or, simply for testing?  Also, if there is an error in my code, I can't seem to find it.  As I said above, the development environment works flawlessly under the same directory structure and source code.

Comment: @Scott-Stroz (anyone), I did some more testing.  It appears that the coldfusion.navigate URL parameter does not like the relative path (again, it works fine on my dev environment, but not on production).  For example, this works:  `<a href='javascript.Coldfusion.navigate('test.cfm');'>`, but this does NOT: `<a href='javascript.Coldfusion.navigate('folder/test.cfm');'>`    thoughts?

Comment: Yea..stop using <cfdiv> and ColdFusion.navigate(). :D Seriously, though, what is different locally and on server? Web server (IIS, Apache)? Is URL path to app the same? Anything you can think of will help.

Comment: @Sean I am advocating NOT using ANY of the UI stuff in ColdFusion. It is typically not optimal and developers frequently hit limitations of the implementation quickly. You are better off using a JS library, like jQuery, to handle AJAXy type stuff like this.

Comment: @Scott, understood... I'm using a combination of both jquery and CF UI.  However, I'm thinking they probably don't like each other, and the client load is bloated because of the supporting files necessary for each.  Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

All:

It appears that I should have been more specific, as this is a very targeted answer.
The file that I was attempting to load was coming from a directory that I had named "manager".  After some testing, it appears that the name "manager" is the issue.  We renamed the directory, and the problem was solved.

In other words, here was my link (I omitted the names, because I thought them irrelevant initially, but here is the actual link):

```
<a href='javascript.Coldfusion.navigate('manager/test.cfm');'>
```

I was forwarded this page by the support team, which seems to reinforce this point:

http://www.giancarlogomez.com/2012/06/directory-of-manager-in-webroot-not.html

Bottom line, don't name a directory in your root folder "manager".  Coldfusion/TomCat reserves that name (at least at the root level).

I'm not sure why they did this (given the occassional use of the word "Manager" as an admin role, and therefore, a common trend to have a directory for this role), but oh well :)